# Descent for complex-analytic spaces

Tags: complex-geometry, stacks, analytic-geometry

I'm basically interested in knowing the difference between complex spaces and schemes when studying stacks. I'd like to use stacks to study moduli problems in complex analytic geometry.

Citing a [proposition](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04W8) from the stacks project:

Let $S$ be a scheme. Let $\{X_i \rightarrow X\}$ be an fpqc covering of algebraic spaces over $S$. Any descent datum on quasi-coherent sheaves for
$\{X_i \rightarrow X\}$ is effective. Moreover, the functor from the category of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules to the category of descent data with respect to $\{X_i\rightarrow X\}$ is fully faithful.

Are there similar/different results for complex spaces? I don't seem to grasp the underlying difficulties. Any references or explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: what's a quasi-coherent sheaf on a complex space?

Comment: @Yosemite Sam:I think it's the same as for ringed spaces: a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus I}\to \mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus J}\to \mathcal{F}\to 0$ is exact for possibly infinite index sets $I$ and $J$.

Comment: Edit: in my previous comment, I meant locally on $X$

Comment: There is no known useful notion of quasi-coherence in analytic geometry; e.g., the definition suggested by Qfwfq is hard to work with if not characterized via coherent sheaves, and the class of sheaves that are locally direct limits of coherent sheaves is *not* stable under countably infinite direct sums (not a paradox!), dooming any hope. You should read Seminaire Cartan, vol. 12, Exp. 9-13 by Grothendieck, esp. 4.10 in Exp. 11 that alludes to the crucial fact (that he didn't reach there) that flat surjective maps of complex-analytic spaces admit *finite* flat sections locally on the base.

Comment: I assume you know material as in the book *Coherent Analytic Sheaves*; if not, read it. The existence of finite flat sections locally on the base for a flat analytic surjection is proved via slicing through Cohen-Macaulay points in fibers (argue from there as in EGA IV$_4$,17.6.2); the existence of such points is proved via the analytic version of Noether normalization. All descent questions for coherent sheaves are thereby settled well. For a flat equivalence relations $d:R\to X\times X$ to have effective quotient, $d$ must factor as $i\circ j$ for open immersion $j$ and closed immersion $i$.

Comment: The reason for the necessity of that condition on $d$ is that diagonals of analytic spaces satisfy that property (since analytic spaces are locally Hausdorff).  Under that assumption, I have a hazy memory of once working out for myself that the descent is effective; in the setting of etale equivalence relations this is modeled on the proof of Prop. 5.18 in section 5 of Ch. 1 of D. Knutson's book *Algebraic Spaces*, and one adapts that to the flat setting by cutting out "finite flat charts" for $X/R$ via slicing of $R \rightarrow X$ through CM-points on $X$ and then CM-points over them in $R$.

Comment: I have always assumed that everything I have said above is well-documented in the literature on deformation theory for complex-analytic spaces, but much of that work is written in German and unfortunately I can only read math papers in German very slowly with a dictionary, so I have never tried to check on this. Maybe someone more familiar with that literature can provide suitable references.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll take a look. Could you point me to the german sources, I am fluent in german fortunately.

Comment: Look at the papers and books of Jürgen Bingener, many of which were focused on adapting to complex-analytic spaces the techniques of Artin for proving representability of functors by algebraic spaces.

Comment: The volume number of Séminaire Cartan mentioned above should be 13 (instead of 12).